# Convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln ^2\left(2n+1\right)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Been struggling with this series.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln ^2\left(2n+1\right)}\right)$$

I know it converges but I can't prove it. Thanks for your time, I’m looking forward to your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\left(\log n\right)^{2}}
> \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\left(\log(2n+1)\right)^{2}},
$$
it is sufficient to prove that the term on the LHS converges. Since
$$
\int\frac{1}{x\left(\log x\right)^{2}}dx=-\frac{1}{\log x}+C,
$$
convergence follows by the integral test.

Answer (score 3):

It's evident that
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^2(2n+1)}<\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}.$$
Note that
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}<\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\int_{n-1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\ln^2 x}=\frac{1}{\ln 2}.$$
Thus your series being convergent follows from
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^2(2n+1)}<\frac{1}{\ln 2}<+\infty.$$

Comment: Beat me to it :-)